# Wordpress plugindevelopment:is_user_logged_in return false

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm developing a plugin that'll manage a user log in.
In my custom log in form, when credentials are submitted I run this code:

```
if( isset( $_POST['login'] ) ){

    $login = wp_signon( array(
        'user_login' => $_POST['username'],
        'user_password' => $_POST['password'],
        'remember' => 'true'
    ), true);

    if( is_wp_error( $login ) ){
        echo $login->get_error_message();
    } else {

        $username = $_POST['username'];

        wp_set_current_user( $login->ID, $_POST['username'] );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $login->ID );
        do_action( 'wp_login', $username );
    }//else

}//if


if( is_user_logged_in() ){ // is_user_logged_in()
    ?><a id="wp-submit" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'ecofriends_logout' => true) ) ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a><?php


} else { 
    ecofriends_login_form(); 
}//else
```

So when the credential are submitted it logs in.
If credentials aren't submitted check if the user is logged in to show a logout link else the login form.

The important fact is that here is_user_logged_in() works fine.

In the function.php file I created a function that manage the logout:

```
function logout(){
if( is_user_logged_in() ){
    wp_logout();
}//if
}//ecofriends_logout
```

but when I call it is_user_logged_in() always return false even if the user has just logged in.

P.S. I'm working on localhost and the login form is called in a page using a shortcode.

Thank you

Comment: Where are you calling the logout() function?

Comment: The folder of the plugin contains all the plugin's files.
The logout() function is called in the same function of the code above which is stored in login.php.

Comment: I've just found out that changing the page in the fron-end website, the user isn't logged in in any page. It logs in just at the moment of the log in page/function but when changing the page or coming back to the login page, the user isn't logged in

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from the comments I think this is what's happening. Your plugin `login.php` file is invoked on every request, which you said calls the logout() function, ergo logging user out every time.

You need to invoke your `logout()` function on user triggered action, like clicking on a log out button or in certain conditions you impose.